# My screen saver no longer shows pictures from albums

Tags: screen, screensaver

My screen saver no longer shows pictures from albums - it says there are no photos but they are there. It will show single pictures and the default directories.

Comment: Are your photos in the photos app, or in some other folder? Are the albums sub-folders within a central folder?

Comment: The photos are in an album in the photos app, and the album appears in the "photos library" selection - they are not in a subfolder.